# Bookstore program using standard algorithms

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm

This is the exercise, from *C++ Primer* 5th edition:

> 10.32: Rewrite the bookstore problem from § 1.6 (p. 24) using a  vector to hold the transactions and various algorithms to do the
> processing.  Use `sort` with your `compareIsbn` function from § 10.3.1 (p.
> 387) to  arrange the transactions in order, and then use `find` and
> `accumulate` to  do the sum."

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

#include "Sales_item.h"

bool compareIsbnv2(const Sales_item &sd1, const Sales_item &sd2) 
{
     return sd1.isbn() < sd2.isbn();
}


int main()
{
     // get input from user 
     std::istream_iterator<Sales_item> item_iter(std::cin), eof;
     std::ostream_iterator<Sales_item> out_iter(std::cout, "\n");

     // make sure we have data to process
     std::vector<Sales_item> trans(item_iter,eof);
     if (item_iter == eof)
     {
        std::cerr << "no data to process!" << std::endl;
     }
     // sorting vector 

     std::sort(trans.begin(), trans.end(), compareIsbnv2); 

     std::cout << "Summing up data..\n";
     for (auto& s : trans)
         std::cout << s << "\n";

     std::cout << "\n\n";
     //Sales_item sum;
     for (auto beg = trans.begin(); beg != trans.end(); beg++)
     {
         auto it = std::find_if_not(beg, trans.end(), [&](Sales_item& item) 
             {return item.isbn() == beg->isbn(); });
         out_iter = std::accumulate(beg, it, Sales_item(beg->isbn()));
         std::cout << "\n\n";
     }
     return 0;
}
```

For some reason that I didn't quite understand the original compare isbn function didn't work, so I'm not sure if the result I get is correct:

#### Input:

```
0-201-12345-X 3 20.00
0-205-12345-X 5 3.00
0-201-12345-X 2 20.00
0-202-12345-X 10 25.00
0-205-12345-X 10 5.00
0-202-12345-X 5 20.00
```

#### Output:

```
0-201-12345-X 5 100 20

0-201-12345-X 2 40 20

0-202-12345-X 15 350 23.3333

0-202-12345-X 5 100 20

0-205-12345-X 15 65 4.33333

0-205-12345-X 10 50 5
```

#### Sales_item.h :

```
#ifndef SALESITEM_H
// we're here only if SALESITEM_H has not yet been defined 
#define SALESITEM_H

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
    // these declarations are explained section 7.2.1, p. 270 
    // and in chapter 14, pages 557, 558, 561
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
    friend bool operator<(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
    friend bool
        operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item() = default;
    Sales_item(const std::string& book) : bookNo(book) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream& is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);

    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;
    // private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
    double revenue = 0.0;
};

// used in chapter 10
inline
bool compareIsbn(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs)
{
    return lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn();
}

// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);

inline bool
operator==(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs)
{
    // must be made a friend of Sales_item
    return lhs.units_sold == rhs.units_sold &&
        lhs.revenue == rhs.revenue &&
        lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn();
}

inline bool
operator!=(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs); // != defined in terms of operator==
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item& rhs)
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
    revenue += rhs.revenue;
    return *this;
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item
operator+(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs)
{
    Sales_item ret(lhs);  // copy (|lhs|) into a local object that we'll return
    ret += rhs;           // add in the contents of (|rhs|) 
    return ret;           // return (|ret|) by value
}

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{
    double price;
    in >> s.bookNo >> s.units_sold >> price;
    // check that the inputs succeeded
    if (in)
        s.revenue = s.units_sold * price;
    else
        s = Sales_item();  // input failed: reset object to default state
    return in;
}

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{
    out << s.isbn() << " " << s.units_sold << " "
        << s.revenue << " " << s.avg_price();
    return out;
}

double Sales_item::avg_price() const
{
    if (units_sold)
        return revenue / units_sold;
    else
        return 0;
}
#endif
```

#### Bookstore problem from § 1.6 (p. 24) :

> We are now ready to solve our original bookstore problem. We need to read a file of
> sales transactions and produce a report that shows, for each book, the total number
> of copies sold, the total revenue, and the average sales price. We’ll assume that all
> the transactions for each ISBN are grouped together in the input.
> Our program will combine the data for each ISBN in a variable named total. We’ll
> use a second variable named trans to hold each transaction we read. If trans and
> total refer to the same ISBN , we’ll update total. Otherwise we’ll print total and
> reset it using the transaction we just read:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
Sales_item total; // variable to hold data for the next transaction
// read the first transaction and ensure that there are data to process
if (std::cin >> total) {
Sales_item trans; // variable to hold the running sum
// read and process the remaining transactions
while (std::cin >> trans) {
// if we're still processing the same book
if (total.isbn() == trans.isbn())
total += trans; // update the running total
else {
// print results for the previous book
std::cout << total << std::endl;
total = trans; // total now refers to the next book
}
}
std::cout << total << std::endl; // print the last transaction
} else {
// no input! warn the user
std::cerr << "No data?!" << std::endl;
return -1; // indicate failure
}
```

Comment: Part of the code is missing. It would be helpful if you could add the definition of `Sales_item`, and in general it's nice if we could copy&paste your code and run it without having to make any changes (like adding the necessary `#include`s).

Comment: It could also help if you tell us what the "problem from § 1.6 (p. 24)" is about.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Presumably the main file has an `#include` for `<algorithm>`, `<iostream>`, `<iterator>`, `<numeric>`, and `<vector>`. It would be nice if those were added, as well as any other include directives.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thank you!, i'm really new to this forum stuff, sorry for inconvenience in my post, have i added all that's necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## About the compare function

> For some reason that I didn't quite understand the original compare isbn function didn't work

The `compareIsbn()` function I see in Sales_item.h compares two items for *equality*, however `sort()` has no use for that, it has to know in which *order* items have to be put. So it needs to be able to compare the *order* of two items.

I have no idea what you needed exactly in chapter 10, but consider that if you have a function that compares the order of two things, you can use that to get the equality as well, at least if there is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order):

```
bool less(const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return a < b;
}

bool equal(const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return !less(a, b) && !less(b, a); // a >= b && b >= a → a == b
}
```

In any case, your `compareIsbnv2()` is a correct function for `std::sort()`.

## Your output contains the same book multiple times

I think the assignment is to have only one line of output for each unique ISBN number. When you have the start and end of a range of identical ISBNs, then you calculate the sum over that, and then skip to the item right after that range. This is simply:

```
for (auto beg = trans.begin(); beg != trans.end();)
{
     auto it = std::find_if_not(…);
     out_iter = std::accumulate(beg, it, Sales_item(beg->isbn()));
     beg = it;
}
```

## Naming

Make sure you give variables concise but meaningful names. Avoid abbreviations, unless they are very common ones, like `i` for a loop iterator. Also avoid naming variables after their type. Here is a list of suggested changes to names:

- `item_iter` -> `input`
- `out_iter` -> `output`
- `trans` -> `transactions`
- `s` -> `transaction`
- `beg` -> `begin` or `start`
- `it` -> `end`, or perhaps `end_of_same` to make it clear this is the end of the range of identical books.

## Incorrect error checking

You are reading the input using `std::istream_iterator`, which is indeed very helpful here. However, the way you check for errors is not correct. Consider that an error might occur before reaching the end of the input, in which case `item_iter` might not be equal to `eof`. It is better to check that `std::cin.eof() == true` to see if the end of the input has been reached successfully.

What is important after that is that the vector holding the transactions is not empty, so instead of comparing the input iterators, write:

```
if (transactions.empty())
{
    std::cerr << "No data to process!\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Note also that if you encounter an error, it is usually a good idea to return an error or throw an exception. Luckily, the rest of your code still works fine if there were no transactions on the input. You might also consider this to be a valid input, in which case you shouldn't print an error message at all.

Note that an error can also happen on the output. What if the output is redirected to a file, but there is an error writing data to disk? If you ignore it and `return 0`, then it might look like your program finished successfully, which is not desirable. Check that `std::cout.good() == true` at the end of the program, and if not, write an error message to `std::cerr` and [`return EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status).

## How it would look in C++23

C++ is continuously evolving, and new features are added to make the life of programmers easier. It looks like the 5th edition of C++ Primer was released in 2012, and thus only covers the standard up to C++11. It's now more than a decade later, and we can do things differently now.

In particular, the ranges library allows us to avoid working with iterators, but operate on ranges instead. Effectively, most algorithms now take a reference to a container as a parameter. Also, there is an easy algorithm to group items in a container based on a predicate using [`std::views::chunk_by()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_by_view). For some reason `std::accumulate()` was never made to work with ranges, but we now have [`std::ranges::fold_left()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left) and related functions that can be used to do the same. Your code could look like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
…
int main()
{
     std::istream_iterator<Sales_item> input(std::cin), eof;
     std::ostream_iterator<Sales_item> output(std::cout, "\n");

     std::vector transactions(input, eof);
     if (!std::cin.eof())
         throw std::runtime_error("Error reading input");

     std::ranges::sort(transactions, compareIsbnv2);

     for (auto chunk: transactions | std::views::chunk_by(compareIsbn))
         out_iter = std::ranges::fold_left_first(chunk, std::plus<>());

     if (!std::cout.good())
         throw std::runtime_error("Error writing output");
}
```

Note that it's currently hard to find compilers and standard libraries that have full C++23 support, so the above will probably not compile for you yet.

Comment: thank you very much first of all!, i completely understood what was wrong in my code.
i know that the book primer 5th is a bit outdated, but i don't feel like abandoning the book, i already started, i find some subjects from c++11 that take me some extra time to learn as i am learning alone from the internet and books.
for know i don't think c++23 is relevant for me as there are more topics that i've just started to learn that some would say are basic like, std::map,std::unordered_map std::set, etc..
primer 5th did not teach me about - std::cin.end() or std::cout.good().

Comment: @matanizhak You should indeed not abandon the book. Virtually everything you can do in C++11 you can still do in later versions of the standard as well, so all that knowledge is not wasted. I just wanted to point out there is more to C++ than what's in the book :)

Comment: thanks!, any recommendations on what to read next ?

Comment: I personally cannot recomend anything (I just didn't read any C++ books in this millenium), but have a look at this [definitive C++ book guide and list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that others created.

Comment: In C++23, I'd probably write `auto transactions = std::ranges::istream_view<Sales_item>(std::cin) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();` rather than creating `input` and `eof` variables.  If we set the streams to throw on error, we could probably perform the entire operation in functional style using `|`.

Comment: Oh, the sort would break the pipeline.  Did you intend to write `std::ranges::sort` there?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I did mean `std::ranges::sort()`, thanks for pointing that out. I could get `std::ranges::to<>()` working on any compiler I tried, so I didn't dare put that in the answer. I still think it's a bit verbose, I'd rather have seen containers take views in their constructors, so you could just have written `std::vector transactions{std::ranges::istream_view<…>(…)}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it couldn't work exactly like that (which would be a vector of views, initialised with one element).  I also haven't successfully used `std::ranges::to()` yet.  :(